# Python error: Cannot import name KafkaConsumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I installed the kafka-python package for Python. I have a kafka producer and consumer running. I want the python code to read the kafka topic and print out the messages.

My python code is below:

```
import sys
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

def kafkatest():
    print "Step 1 complete"
    consumer=KafkaConsumer('test',bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
    for message in consumer:
        print "Next message"
        print message


if __name__=="__main__":
    kafkatest()
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Python27>python.exe kafka.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "kafka.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer   File "C:\Python27\kafka.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer ImportError: cannot import name KafkaConsumer
```

Any suggestions on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 25):

You have named your file `kafka.py`.  Now when you run it, python encounters the following statement inside it:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
```

So it must find a module called `kafka`.  How does it known where to look?  Well it looks in the directories on `sys.path`, the **first of which is initialised to be the directory of the input script**.

Thus, the file it finds and attempts to look in is **your** module called `kafka`, which does not define `KafkaConsumer` and hence the error.

Effectively, you are importing yourself.

**Moral**: *Stop naming your scripts with identical names to system libraries or external packages that you're hoping to use*.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you!

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan you should accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Not my question @acat

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan gotcha, I see that now. must have misread

Comment: Any other suggestions. I most definately do not have a file named kafka.py (or anything with the word kafka)